# sets without perfect subset in a non-separable completely metrizable space

Tags: descriptive-set-theory, gn.general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a completely metrizable (but not separable) space. Suppose $D$ is a Borel (actually $F_{\sigma}$) subset of $X$. Is there any logical relation between the following statements?

[1] $D$ does not contain a non-empty perfect subset of $X$ (There is no $P \subseteq D$ such that $P$ is non-empty, closed in $X$, and has no isolated points).

[2] $D$ is a countable union of discrete subsets of $X$.

If [1] and [2] are not equivalent, what conditions would be equivalent with [1]?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 5):

[2]$\Rightarrow$ [1]. It is easy to check that each discrete subset $D’$ of a perfect space $P$ is nowhere dense in $P$.  Now suppose that $D$ is a countable union of discrete subsets of $X$ and $D$ contains a non-empty perfect subset $P$ of $X$. By Theorem 4.3.11 from [Eng], $P$ is completely metrizable. By Theorem 2.4 from [Eng], $P$ is a Baire space, therefore it cannot be a countable union of its discrete subsets.

[1]$\Rightarrow$ [2]. I googled a little and found articles [Sto] and [Kou]. In the beginning of the paper [Kou] it is written the following: “A classical theorem of Suslin states that every analytic subset of a Polish (separable complete metric) space is either countable, or contains a copy of the Cantor set. A generalization to the non-separable case has been obtained by El’kin [1]: every absolutely analytic space (i.e. homeomorphic to a [Suslin subset](http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enwiki/2654809) of some complete metric space) is either $\sigma$-discrete, or contains a copy of the Cantor set. This theorem had previously been proved by Stone [Sto] for absolutely Borel spaces”.

Concerning descriptive generalizations for Polish spaces, I recall that book [Kech] contains The Perfect Sets Theorems for Borel (13.6) (by Alexandrov and Hausdorff), Analytic (14.13) (by Souslin), Co-Analytic (32.2) and Projective (38.17) (by Davis) Sets: each such subset of a Polish space either is countable or else it contains a copy of Cantor set.

It seems that these results can be trivially generalized to locally separable metrizable spaces (by [Eng, Ex. 4.4.F.C] each such space is a disjoint sum of separable spaces) and to $\sigma$-discrete subsets instead of countable.

I remark that if we drop descriptive conditions for the set $D$ (like Borelness) then [1] does not imply [2]. Let $D$ be a Bernstein subset (see [Cic]) of the real line $\mathbb R$ (for non-separability we can take as $X$ a disjoint sum of uncountably many copies of $\mathbb R$).  Each discrete subset of a hereditarily separable space (in particular, of a second countable space) is countable. Therefore each countable union of discrete subsets of $\mathbb R$ is countable. But if $D$ were countable, then $\mathbb R\setminus D$ will be a completely metrizable space as a non-empty $G_\delta$ subset of a completely metrizable space by Theorem 4.3.23 from [Eng]. Therefore $\mathbb R\setminus D$ will contain a copy $C$ of a Cantor set, [Cic] a contradiction.

*References*

[Cic] Jacek Cichoń. [*On Bernstein Sets*](http://prac.im.pwr.wroc.pl/~cichon/Math/Bernstein.pdf).

[Eng]  Ryszard Engelking, *[General Topology](http://webfile.ru/6665165)*, 2nd ed., Heldermann, Berlin, 1989.

[HC] R. C. Haworth, R. C. McCoy, *[Baire spaces](http://webfile.ru/60bab371bf228dca38bd68e6015d32d5)*, Warszawa, Panstwowe Wydawnictwo Naukowe, 1977.

[Kech] Alexander S. Kechris. *[Classical Descriptive Set Theory](http://webfile.ru/6546968)* , Springer, 1995.

[Kou] George Koumoullis. *[Cantor sets in Prokhorov spaces](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm124/fm124110.pdf)*.

[Sto] A. H. Stone. [*Kernel constructions and Borel sets*](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1963-107-01/S0002-9947-1963-0151935-0/S0002-9947-1963-0151935-0.pdf).

Comment: I must be missing something. You seem to claim that $1\to2$ fails even for $X=\mathbb R$. However, this contradicts the Cantor–Bendixson theorem.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Oops, I missed that $D$ is a Borel subset of $\mathbb R$. Thanks. I'll try to correct my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, we found your answers very helpful. The equivalence of [1] and [2] follows from the theorem by Koumoullis that you suggested.

Comment: I suppose that by "Stone [14]" you meant Stone [Sto]. You also mentioned this reference in your post: "El’kin [1]". It is not listed in your list of references at the end of the post.